# Sending a zip file with SOAP (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, soap

I imported the WSDL file into the DLL, but when I try to send the file, I get the "Cannot read that as a ZipFile" error. When sending the file, it sends as Base64, I think the problem stems here. Is it possible to send the zip file directly as BinaryData?

**Function code:**

```
function EBookSender(kullaniciAdi, parola, dosyaYolu, yil: String;
  periyod: Integer): String;
var
  myService: IeBookService;
  sessionCode: string;
  files: TransferDocument;
  Zip: TZipFile;
  zipArray: TArray<System.Byte>;
  loginResult: Boolean;
  documentResult: Boolean;
  documentNumber: String;
begin

  try
    try
      myService := eBookService.GetIeBookService();   
      Zip := TZipFile.Create;
      Zip.Open('C:\Temp\' + ExtractFileName(dosyaYolu).Split(['.'])[0] +
        '.zip', zmWrite);
      Zip.Add(dosyaYolu);
      Zip.Close;
      Zip.Open('C:\Temp\' + ExtractFileName(dosyaYolu).Split(['.'])[0] +
        '.zip', zmRead);

      Zip.Read(0, zipArray);

      myService.Login(kullaniciAdi, parola, loginResult, sessionCode);

      files := TransferDocument.Create;
      files.Period := periyod;
      files.Year := yil;
      files.FileName := ExtractFileName(dosyaYolu).Split(['.'])[0] + '.zip';
      files.BinaryData := zipArray;

      myService.Transfer(sessionCode, files, documentResult, documentNumber);

      // Result := sessionCode;

      Result := loginResult.ToString();
    except
      on exp: Exception do
      begin
        Result := exp.Message;
      end;
      //
    end;

  finally
    FreeAndNil(Zip);
  end;

end;
```

**I imported the WSDL file belonging to the SOAP service. The codes generated after importing are as follows:**

```
unit eBookService;

interface

uses Soap.InvokeRegistry, Soap.SOAPHTTPClient, System.Types, Soap.XSBuiltIns;

const
  IS_OPTN = $0001;
  IS_NLBL = $0004;
  IS_REF  = $0080;

    type
      TransferDocument2    = class;                 { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.WebService.Models"[GblCplx] }
  TransferDocument     = class;                 { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.WebService.Models"[GblElm] }
  DataModel2           = class;                 { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models"[GblCplx] }
  DataModel            = class;                 { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models"[GblElm] }
  ConnectorAccountRights2 = class;              { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models"[GblCplx] }
  ConnectorAccountRights = class;               { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models"[GblElm] }

  {$SCOPEDENUMS ON}
  { "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Common.Base"[GblSmpl] }
  Enums_BookType = (Journal, Ledger);

  {$SCOPEDENUMS OFF}

  TransferDocument2 = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FBinaryData: TArray<System.Byte>;
    FBinaryData_Specified: boolean;
    FFileName: string;
    FFileName_Specified: boolean;
    FPeriod: Integer;
    FPeriod_Specified: boolean;
    FYear: string;
    FYear_Specified: boolean;
    function  GetBinaryData(Index: Integer): TArray<System.Byte>;
    procedure SetBinaryData(Index: Integer; const ATArray: TArray<System.Byte>);
    function  BinaryData_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    function  GetFileName(Index: Integer): string;
    procedure SetFileName(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  FileName_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    function  GetPeriod(Index: Integer): Integer;
    procedure SetPeriod(Index: Integer; const AInteger: Integer);
    function  Period_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    function  GetYear(Index: Integer): string;
    procedure SetYear(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  Year_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property BinaryData: TArray<System.Byte>  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read GetBinaryData write SetBinaryData stored BinaryData_Specified;
    property FileName:   string               Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read GetFileName write SetFileName stored FileName_Specified;
    property Period:     Integer              Index (IS_OPTN) read GetPeriod write SetPeriod stored Period_Specified;
    property Year:       string               Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read GetYear write SetYear stored Year_Specified;
  end;

  TransferDocument = class(TransferDocument2)
  private
  published
  end;

  DataModel2 = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FData: TArray<System.Byte>;
    FData_Specified: boolean;
    FUniqueId: string;
    FUniqueId_Specified: boolean;
    function  GetData(Index: Integer): TArray<System.Byte>;
    procedure SetData(Index: Integer; const ATArray: TArray<System.Byte>);
    function  Data_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    function  GetUniqueId(Index: Integer): string;
    procedure SetUniqueId(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
    function  UniqueId_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property Data:     TArray<System.Byte>  Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read GetData write SetData stored Data_Specified;
    property UniqueId: string               Index (IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL) read GetUniqueId write SetUniqueId stored UniqueId_Specified;
  end;

  DataModel = class(DataModel2)
  private
  published
  end;

  ConnectorAccountRights2 = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FAllowToUseEDefter: Boolean;
    FAllowToUseEDefter_Specified: boolean;
    FAllowToUseEDenetim: Boolean;
    FAllowToUseEDenetim_Specified: boolean;
    function  GetAllowToUseEDefter(Index: Integer): Boolean;
    procedure SetAllowToUseEDefter(Index: Integer; const ABoolean: Boolean);
    function  AllowToUseEDefter_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
    function  GetAllowToUseEDenetim(Index: Integer): Boolean;
    procedure SetAllowToUseEDenetim(Index: Integer; const ABoolean: Boolean);
    function  AllowToUseEDenetim_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
  published
    property AllowToUseEDefter:  Boolean  Index (IS_OPTN) read GetAllowToUseEDefter write SetAllowToUseEDefter stored AllowToUseEDefter_Specified;
    property AllowToUseEDenetim: Boolean  Index (IS_OPTN) read GetAllowToUseEDenetim write SetAllowToUseEDenetim stored AllowToUseEDenetim_Specified;
  end;
    
  ConnectorAccountRights = class(ConnectorAccountRights2)
  private
  published
  end;

  IeBookService = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{2FAB8159-6B26-4D5E-B364-EA454B0B248A}']
    procedure Login(const userName: string; const password: string; out LoginResult: Boolean; out sessionId: string); stdcall;
    procedure Transfer(const sessionId: string; const document: TransferDocument2; out TransferResult: Boolean; out documentNumber: string); stdcall;
    procedure TransferWithDivisionDays(const sessionId: string; const document: TransferDocument2; const startDay: Byte; const endDay: Byte; out TransferWithDivisionDaysResult: Boolean; out documentNumber: string
                                       ); stdcall;
    function  GetBookFiles(const sessionId: string; const BookType: Enums_BookType; const Period: Integer; const Year: string; out GetBookFilesResult: Boolean): DataModel2; stdcall;
    function  GetConnectorAccountRights(const sessionId: string): ConnectorAccountRights2; stdcall;
  end;

function GetIeBookService(UseWSDL: Boolean=System.False; Addr: string=''; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO = nil): IeBookService;
    
implementation
  uses System.SysUtils;

function GetIeBookService(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): IeBookService;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://xxxx.com/eBookService.svc?wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http://xxxx.com/eBookService.svc';
  defSvc  = 'eBookService';
  defPrt  = 'CustomBinding_IeBookService';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as IeBookService);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;
   
function TransferDocument2.GetBinaryData(Index: Integer): TArray<System.Byte>;
begin
  Result := FBinaryData;
end;

procedure TransferDocument2.SetBinaryData(Index: Integer; const ATArray: TArray<System.Byte>);
begin
  FBinaryData := ATArray;
  FBinaryData_Specified := True;
end;

function TransferDocument2.BinaryData_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FBinaryData_Specified;
end;

function TransferDocument2.GetFileName(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := FFileName;
end;

procedure TransferDocument2.SetFileName(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
begin
  FFileName := Astring;
  FFileName_Specified := True;
end;

function TransferDocument2.FileName_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FFileName_Specified;
end;

function TransferDocument2.GetPeriod(Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := FPeriod;
end;

procedure TransferDocument2.SetPeriod(Index: Integer; const AInteger: Integer);
begin
  FPeriod := AInteger;
  FPeriod_Specified := True;
end;

function TransferDocument2.Period_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FPeriod_Specified;
end;

function TransferDocument2.GetYear(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := FYear;
end;

procedure TransferDocument2.SetYear(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
begin
  FYear := Astring;
  FYear_Specified := True;
end;

function TransferDocument2.Year_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FYear_Specified;
end;

function DataModel2.GetData(Index: Integer): TArray<System.Byte>;
begin
  Result := FData;
end;

procedure DataModel2.SetData(Index: Integer; const ATArray: TArray<System.Byte>);
begin
  FData := ATArray;
  FData_Specified := True;
end;

function DataModel2.Data_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FData_Specified;
end;

function DataModel2.GetUniqueId(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  Result := FUniqueId;
end;

procedure DataModel2.SetUniqueId(Index: Integer; const Astring: string);
begin
  FUniqueId := Astring;
  FUniqueId_Specified := True;
end;

function DataModel2.UniqueId_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FUniqueId_Specified;
end;

function ConnectorAccountRights2.GetAllowToUseEDefter(Index: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FAllowToUseEDefter;
end;

procedure ConnectorAccountRights2.SetAllowToUseEDefter(Index: Integer; const ABoolean: Boolean);
begin
  FAllowToUseEDefter := ABoolean;
  FAllowToUseEDefter_Specified := True;
end;

function ConnectorAccountRights2.AllowToUseEDefter_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FAllowToUseEDefter_Specified;
end;

function ConnectorAccountRights2.GetAllowToUseEDenetim(Index: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := FAllowToUseEDenetim;
end;

procedure ConnectorAccountRights2.SetAllowToUseEDenetim(Index: Integer; const ABoolean: Boolean);
begin
  FAllowToUseEDenetim := ABoolean;
  FAllowToUseEDenetim_Specified := True;
end;

function ConnectorAccountRights2.AllowToUseEDenetim_Specified(Index: Integer): boolean;
begin
  Result := FAllowToUseEDenetim_Specified;
end;

initialization
  { IeBookService }
  InvRegistry.RegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'http://tempuri.org/', 'utf-8');
  InvRegistry.RegisterDefaultSOAPAction(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'http://tempuri.org/IeBookService/%operationName%');
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(IeBookService), ioDocument);
  InvRegistry.RegisterInvokeOptions(TypeInfo(IeBookService), ioSOAP12);
  { IeBookService.Login }
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'Login', 'userName', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'Login', 'password', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'Login', 'sessionId', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  { IeBookService.Transfer }
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'Transfer', 'sessionId', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'Transfer', 'document', '',
                                '[Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.WebService.Models"]', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'Transfer', 'documentNumber', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  { IeBookService.TransferWithDivisionDays }
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'TransferWithDivisionDays', 'sessionId', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'TransferWithDivisionDays', 'document', '',
                                '[Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.WebService.Models"]', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'TransferWithDivisionDays', 'documentNumber', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  { IeBookService.GetBookFiles }
  InvRegistry.RegisterMethodInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'GetBookFiles', '',
                                 '[ReturnName="result"]', IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'GetBookFiles', 'sessionId', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'GetBookFiles', 'BookType', '',
                                '[Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Common.Base"]');
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'GetBookFiles', 'Year', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'GetBookFiles', 'result', '',
                                '[Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models"]', IS_NLBL);
  { IeBookService.GetConnectorAccountRights }
  InvRegistry.RegisterMethodInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'GetConnectorAccountRights', '',
                                 '[ReturnName="GetConnectorAccountRightsResult"]', IS_OPTN or IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'GetConnectorAccountRights', 'sessionId', '',
                                '', IS_NLBL);
  InvRegistry.RegisterParamInfo(TypeInfo(IeBookService), 'GetConnectorAccountRights', 'GetConnectorAccountRightsResult', '',
                                '[Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models"]', IS_NLBL);
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(TransferDocument2, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.WebService.Models', 'TransferDocument2', 'TransferDocument');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(TransferDocument, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.WebService.Models', 'TransferDocument');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSInfo(TypeInfo(Enums_BookType), 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Common.Base', 'Enums_BookType', 'Enums.BookType');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(DataModel2, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models', 'DataModel2', 'DataModel');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(DataModel, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models', 'DataModel');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(ConnectorAccountRights2, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models', 'ConnectorAccountRights2', 'ConnectorAccountRights');
  RemClassRegistry.RegisterXSClass(ConnectorAccountRights, 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBook.Services.Core.Models', 'ConnectorAccountRights');

end.
```

Comment: You basically have three choices: the CDATA tag, encoded (often BASE64) or put in a reference to a URL where the binary data can be retrieved separately.

Comment: @Brian CDATA can't be used for binary content.

Comment: @Olivier as long as it doesn't contain  `"]]>"` it works. Not a good option but it is an option.

Comment: @Brian An XML parser will try to interpret the CDATA as a string (usually in UTF-8). A binary content will contain invalid UTF-8 sequences, which will trigger an error.

Comment: How do I add the CDATA tag to Byte Array?

Comment: CDATA stands for **character** data. As already said, it's not for binary content.

Comment: Your code does not send the zip file. It compresses the `dosyaYolu` file and extracts it, so you end up sending `dosyaYolu` instead of the zip.

Comment: @Olivier The "dosyaYolu" variable contains the path to an XLS file. How can I add this XLS file to the zip file and send it?

Comment: You can load the zip file with [`TFile.ReadAllBytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllBytes).

Comment: @Olivier Problem fix it. Thanks.